# Analysing timeseries data using Panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have some timeseries data as per below that I want to do some specific analysis on

```
"timestamp","epic","closeprice_bid","closeprice_ask","last_traded_volume"
"2020-03-24 12:00:00","KA.D.BARC.DAILY.IP","91.17","91.38","7836277"
"2020-03-24 13:00:00","KA.D.BARC.DAILY.IP","90.33","90.66","8001075"
"2020-03-24 14:00:00","KA.D.BARC.DAILY.IP","89.96","90.22","11490520"
"2020-03-24 15:00:00","KA.D.BARC.DAILY.IP","91.62","91.89","9014323"
"2020-03-24 16:00:00","KA.D.BARC.DAILY.IP","93.84","94.23","7270054"
"2020-03-24 16:00:00","KA.D.BARC.DAILY.IP","93.84","94.23","7270054.0"
"2020-03-25 08:00:00","KA.D.BARC.DAILY.IP","109.47","109.89","25414762.0"
"2020-03-25 08:00:00","KA.D.BARC.DAILY.IP","109.47","109.89","25414762
```

I want to simulate a basic trading strategy whereby using pandas dataframes I am able to analyse the timeseries data by 1) checking to see if there was a difference of ≥1% or ≤1% between the previous days last closeprice_bid and today's first closeprice_bid 2) for every hour of data check if the closeprice_bid is ≥3% or ≤3% of today's opening closeprice_bid.

Can someone please provide some guidance as to how go about doing the analysis described above using pandas

I have loaded the data into a df using the code below:

```
cols = ['timestamp', 'epic', 'closeprice_bid', 'closeprice_ask','last_traded_volume']
stock_data = pd.read_csv('barc.csv', header=0, names=cols)
stock_data['closeprice_bid'] = pd.to_numeric(stock_data['closeprice_bid'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: So basically you want to check if the difference between the closeprice_bid between one row and the next row is greater than  1%, right?

Comment: No I want to check is the following: 1) checking to see if there was a difference of ≥1% or ≤1% between the previous days last closeprice_bid and today's first closeprice_bid . If there is a difference then for every hour of new data check if the current closeprice_bid is ≥3% or ≤3% today's first closeprice_bid.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like :

```
 (stock_data['closeprice_bid'].shift(-1) -stock_data['closeprice_bid'])/stock_data['closeprice_bid'] > 0.01
```

and similar for per hour case.

Comment: Thanks for this but can you kindly explain what this code is doing. I have ran it and it executes without error but I am not sure what the output means

Comment: It will return a pandas series of true false,... which will tell you if your conditiion is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.date
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.time
df.sort_values(by=['date', 'time'], inplace=True)
first = df.groupby(by='date').first()['closeprice_bid']
df_first = first.to_frame().reset_index()
last = df.groupby(by='date').last()['closeprice_bid']
df_last = last.to_frame().reset_index()

df_merged = df_first.merge(df_last, left_on=['date'], right_on=['date'])
df_merged.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)
df_merged['pct_change'] = df_merged.pct_change(axis=1)['closeprice_bid_y']
df_merged['greater_than_1'] = df_merged['pct_change'] > 1
print(df_merged)

            closeprice_bid_x  closeprice_bid_y  pct_change  greater_than_1
date
2020-03-24             91.17             93.84    0.029286           False
2020-03-25            109.47            109.47    0.000000           False
```

Comment: Thanks for this but can you kindly explain what this code is doing. I have ran it and it executes without error but I am not sure what the output means

Comment: It is sorting by date and time, grouping by date, getting the first and last row for that date, creating dataframes for first and last row, merging those dataframes and showing first and last values of closeprice_bid side by side  as 2 columns and calculating percent change for those 2 columns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but  I would like to calculate the percentage difference between the previous day's last closeprice_bid and today's first closeprice_bid.

Comment: You can try modifying the code now. I guess you edited the question today.

Comment: Yes I realised it wasn't quite clear so I rewrote it I will try modifying. Thanks for your help though dude really appreciate it!

Comment: Apologies it was quite unclear so I reworded it. Thanks for your help dude really appreciate it will try modifying the code hopefully can get it to work!